# [JIRA]How to know a custom field's creation time

Tags: jira

Is there a way to know certain JIRA custom field's creation time? or even which account created it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the JIRA Auditor plugin which tracks access to the page that adds fields.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.plugenta.jiraauditor